# How do I get rid of CS4014 warnings for *.g.cs files?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-template-studio

I've been getting the CS4014 warning in Visual Studio developing UWP apps, and can't figure out what to do with them. I know there's a way to suppress them in VS, but I don't want to suppress all CS4014 warnings altogether.

> Warning CS4014 Because this call is not awaited, execution of the
>   current method continues before the call is completed. Consider
>   applying the 'await' operator to the result of the call.

The reason it's troubling is it is showing up on *.g.cs files which are generated automatically by VS, I assume.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** If there's someone more knoweledgeable who can tell me why this isn't good, please do.

After some time trying to figure this out, I realized that the *.g.cs files are generated from my XAML. The warning shows up for events bound to methods in my ViewModel that are not synchronous(?)

Example PageExample.xaml.g.cs:

```
case 15: // Views\PageExample.xaml line 72
    this.obj15 = (global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ToggleMenuFlyoutItem)target;
    this.obj15Click = (global::System.Object p0, global::Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs p1) =>
    {
        //Warning CS4014 because of line below. 
        //I can add await before this line all I want, 
        //but the file gets regenerated anyway.
        this.dataRoot.ViewModel.Refresh();
    };
    ((global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ToggleMenuFlyoutItem)target).Click += obj15Click;
    this.bindingsTracking.RegisterTwoWayListener_15(this.obj15);
    break;
```

Example XAML PageExample.xaml:

```
<ToggleMenuFlyoutItem Text="Toggle" Click="{x:Bind ViewModel.Refresh}" />
```

Example ViewModel.cs:

```
//Warning CS4014 on the .g.cs file because this is async
public async Task Refresh()
{
      //code you actually want
}
```

I've tried just changing to `async void` on the `Refresh` method but it seems to have an effect that caused timing issues in my case.
This is what seems to work. Ugly, but seems to address the warning.

ViewModel.cs:

```
//No more warning CS4014 since it's async void
public async void Refresh()
{
      await RefreshAsync();
}
public async Task RefreshAsync()
{
      //code you actually want
}
```

Per Jon's comment, I suppose, this reasonable:

```
//no need to be async void
public void Refresh()
{
    //discard
    _ = RefreshAsync();
}
```

Comment: Fundamentally it looks like the generated code expects `Refresh()` to be synchronous. Are you able to write synchronous refresh code instead, and call your *asynchronous* refresh method `RefreshAsync`?

Comment: Hi Jon! Makes sense. Edited to hopefully line up with what you just said.

Comment: No, that's still refreshing asynchronously. You either need to be able to refresh synchronously, or somehow change the generated code (e.g. via a script that does the right thing after generation, as a hacky option).

Comment: Hmm. `RefreshAsync` is littered with `await` lines that, to me, seems harder to convert so `RefreshAsync` can be turned synchronous (moved over to `Refresh`). This is hacky, too. Right?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't see what you're proposing. If you really can't refresh synchronously, I think you're going to have to work out a way of changing the generated code. (I'm now unavailable for several hours, so won't be able to add any more comments.)